# variance of $n$ bernoulli trials and central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the variance of $n$ Bernoulli trials. I need this information to use the central limit theorem to calculate some probabilities. here are my thoughts so far. I am a little lost.

**question**

suppose there's an exam with 50 questions, each with 4 possible choices, only one of which is correct.

each correct answer is worth +10 points and each incorrect answer is worth -5 points. answers are chosen randomly.

1. what would be the variance of total scores on this exam using this approach?
2. what is the probability of scoring more than 50 total points on the test using this approach?

**1) variance**

i know $p = \frac{1}{4}$ and $n = 50$.

I think $E(X_{1})$ is given by the weighted average of the possible points one can earn for this question: $E(X_{1}) = 10 \cdot \frac{1}{4} - 5 \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{10}{4} - \frac{15}{4} = \frac{-5}{4}$.

but the formula for the variance of a binomial random variable (which is a sum of Bernoulli random variables) is $np(1-p)$, so I think this means that $Var(X_{1}) = 50 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{150}{16}$.

I am stuck here because this calculation for variance doesn't consider the different values assigned to correct (+10) and incorrect (-5) test answers. I tried calculating $Var(X_{1})$ using $E(X_{1}^{2}) - E(X_{1})^{2}$ and got $\frac{675}{16}$, which I think is correct, but only for $X_{1}$ (first randomly chosen answer) and not the whole test, which is what I need.

what am I missing here?

**2) central limit theorem**

for this part, all I can say with any certainty so far is that the maximum possible score is $n \cdot 10 = 500$ points and the minimum possible score is $n \cdot -5 = -250$. but I think that once I find $Var(X)$, I'll be able to use the normal distribution to find $1 - P(X \leq 50) = P(X > 50)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance for one question is correct. Nothing wrong. Now you can consider the 50 question as 50 independent random variables with $\mathbb E(X_i)=-\frac54$ and $Var(X_i)=\frac{675}{16}$.

For $n$ i.i.d random variables we have $Var(nX)=n\cdot Var(X)=50\cdot \frac{675}{16}$. Thus the standard deviation is $\sigma\approx 6.4952$ And the expected value for all 50 questions is $E(X)=-50\cdot \frac54= -\frac{125}2=-62.5$

Now you can apply the central limit theorem. Let $S_{50}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} X_i$, where $X_i$ is the payoff of the random variable for one question.

$$P(S_{50}>50)=1-P(S_{50}\leq 50)$$ $$\approx 1-\Phi\left(\frac{50+0.5+62.5}{6.4952} \right)=1-\Phi(17.397)=1-1=0$$

$+0.5$ is the continuity correction factor.

Answer (score 2):

A binomial distribution counts successes for a fixed number of Bernoulli trials, but your random variable is not actually a binomial distribution. It is, however, based on one. To make this explicit, let $X_{\mathrm{B}}$ denote the corresponding binomial random variable with $n = 50$ and $p = \frac14$, which takes values $\{0, 1, \dots, 50\}$.

Your variable $X_1$ has $51$ corresponding *but different* values $\{-250, -235, \dots, 500\}$, obtained via a linear transformation of the values of $X_B$. To determine this function $X_1 = a + bX_{\mathrm{B}}$, consider two easy points to calculate. The score when all questions are incorrect: $-5 \cdot 50 = -250$ and the score when all questions are correct: $10 \cdot 50 = 500$. The intercept is $a = -250$ and slope is
$$
b = \frac{500 - (-250)}{50 - 0} = 15,  
$$
so $X_1 = -250 + 15X_{\mathrm{B}}$. You can intuitively see the $b = 15$ point spread between getting any particular question correct vs. incorrect.

Now, it's a standard exercise (*that you should definitely do yourself if you haven't yet*) to work out how expected value and variance behave under linear transformations:
$$
\operatorname{E}(a + bX_{\mathrm{B}}) 
= a + b\,\operatorname{E}(X_{\mathrm{B}}) 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\operatorname{Var}(a + bX_{\mathrm{B}}) 
= b^2\operatorname{Var}(X_{\mathrm{B}}).
$$

Therefore, since you know formulas for $\operatorname{E}(X_{\mathrm{B}})$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_{\mathrm{B}})$, you can work out the corresponding statistics for $X_1$. I'll let you take it from here.